# How to limit access just for one user on external drive folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, permissions, external-hard-drive

I have an external drive with one TB capacity, which is being used by others also to store their personal data. Usually the hard drive is being used with different versions of windows some times I guess with other OS also. But here the issue is I want to protect the data from unauthorized access or deletion.

How can I limit the access for me only on a folder which is in external hard drive?

Here I don't want to use any other software as it becomes difficult for me if I want to use the data when I connected it to other computers without that software.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the impossible. Either use encryption software, or buy another disk just for your own use.